# how to identify IE error Messages

Tags: php, internet-explorer

i m  working on a php page where css, JS and Jquery is included.
in Mozilla it show Error message on console or in firebug
 but in IE it display

```
Line:1597
Char:9
Error:Invalid Argument
Code:0
URL: blah blah blah
```

now how do i know this error??
in fact there is no 1597 lines in my php code

and if i extract all JS and CSS(included)
then how do i calculate line no. 1597? do i extract each and every CSS and JS in the order they are included?
either it should be reflect in source code

how do i understand this error reporting message??? is there any way/ tool to identify exact what error IE want to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this msdn blog entry: [JScript Debugger in Internet Explorer 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/jscript/archive/2008/03/13/jscript-debugger-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx):

> To get to the debugger just press SHIFT+F12, or click the developer tools icon in the command bar.

edit: For IE7  there is a developer toolbar from microsoft that you can download separately from [the microsoft download center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en):

> The Microsoft Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar provides a variety of tools for quickly creating, understanding, and troubleshooting Web pages.

Also have a read of [IEBlog: Scripting Debugging in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx)

Comment: i use script debugger tool, then it display error lines with code, i posted it in my new question[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171531/ie-display-error-in-prototype-js-line-no-1597), please tell me where is the error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how IE calculates the given line and char-number and I've also been frustrated with this several times.

Mostly I try to track down the error with Firebug (for Firefox) and then try to transfer it to IE. If that doesn't work, I delete suspicious codeblocks to see where the error hides :)

Programs similar to Firebug (though I haven't been using them) are "IE Developer Toolbar" and "DebugBar". Also "Firebug Lite" (a JS that emulates Firebug-functions in IE) could be of help: http://getfirebug.com/lite

Comment: that is not working dear. actually im using some prototype light windows, it appear on click some link but gone away. in FF it's working fine