# IE display error in prototype.js line no. 1597

Tags: php, prototypejs

i m using lightwindow using prototype.js, IE display error when lighwindow appear, i m writing lines where problem occur, please suggest me where is the error and how to rectifi it

```
setStyle: function(element, styles, camelized) {
    element = $(element);
    var elementStyle = element.style;

    for (var property in styles)
      if (property == 'opacity') element.setOpacity(styles[property])
      else
        elementStyle[(property == 'float' || property == 'cssFloat') ? // error show in this line
          (elementStyle.styleFloat === undefined ? 'cssFloat' : 'styleFloat') :
          (camelized ? property : property.camelize())] = styles[property];

    return element;
  },
```

Comment: It just says "error" or is there a more detailed error message?

Comment: Even if not needed, I'd start by using angle brackets for your if blocks and dissolving the nested ternary operator. The code is a pain to read and I wouldn't wonder if this is the reason for the error.

Comment: @Gordon, I think this is from the original prototype code, so you will have to talk to them :)

Comment: Would you by any chance be trying to use setStyle on an animated GIF?

Comment: @Pekka I've seen lots of errors raised by Prototype that ultimately stemmed from code *using* the framework, especially with IE that already chokes on a missing semicolon.

Comment: @Gordon, yes, that's my theory too. The "original code" remark was in regards to your code style comment (not to say you're not right, but it's the prototype team's coding style, not the OP's).

Comment: @Pekka Oooh, I see. Wow. I'd never expected this unreadable code to be allowed in Prototype. Sorry to the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prototype.js code is most likely fine, it's probably a `setStyle()` call on an element that doesn't exist.

If you use Internet Explorer 8, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the developer tools. Change to the "script" tab and then find the Stack Trace. **The stack trace will show you the point where the offending `setStyle()` call was made**. That might already give you a hint wnat's wrong; if it doesn't, come back with that info.

You can do the same with Firefox and [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com).

Comment: in firefox this is running perfectly, and i m using IE7 with debuger script.
on the other page this script running ok, with same code on IE

Comment: Well, what does the debugger tell you?

Comment: What does the stack trace tell you? Where was the invalid argument made? What is the JS in that line?

Comment: i have mentiond in  the question abt that line of error(just after else), i didn't see stack trace and script debugger crashes now. i m downloading IE 8 for debugging

Comment: You need to find the point the function was called from. Yeah, IE8 is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @Gordon: Just discovered it the other day! It's great.

Comment: @ILP, here's another one it looks like you might want to accept?

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (var property in styles)
      if (property == 'opacity') element.setOpacity(styles[property]);
      else /*@cc_on @*/
/*@if(@_jscript_version >= 5)
try{
@end @*/
        elementStyle[(property == 'float' || property == 'cssFloat') ?
          (Object.isUndefined(elementStyle.styleFloat) ? 'cssFloat' : 'styleFloat') :
            property] = styles[property];/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if(@_jscript_version >= 5)
} catch(e){};
@end @*/
```